# Point $E$ on base $AD$ of trapezoid $ABCD$ is such that $AE = BC$. Segments $CA$ and $CE$ intersects diagonal $BD$ at $O$ and $P$ respectively.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Point $E$ on base $AD$ of trapezoid $ABCD$ is such that $AE = BC$. Segments $CA$ and $CE$ intersects diagonal $BD$ at $O$ and $P$ respectively. Prove that if $BO = PD$ then $AD^2 = BC^2 + AD \times BC$

On solving this problem, the author wrote that $BO: OD = DP:PB = k$ But I don't get why, what theorem did he apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

First notice that because $AE=BC$ and $AE\parallel BC$, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. Because $BO = DP$, we see that $DO = BP$, and hence $$\frac{BO}{OD} = \frac{DP}{BP}$$ (which is the place you were stuck at). Then, notice that $$\frac{BC}{AD} = \frac{BO}{DO} = \frac{DP}{BP} = \frac{DE}{BC}\implies BC^2 = DE\cdot AD$$
we can rewrite this using the fact that $BC = AE$ as $$BC\cdot(AD-ED) = BC^2 = DE\cdot AD = DE\cdot(BC+ED)$$
which gives us $$2BC\cdot ED + ED^2 = AD\cdot BC$$
Hence,
$$AD^2 = (BC+DE)^2 = BC^2 + 2BC\cdot ED + ED^2 = BC^2+AD\cdot BC$$
as desired.

Comment: I understand you very well and Thanks for the answer but I still don't get why $BC:AD = BO:OD$

Comment: It's because $BC\parallel AD$ and $\triangle BCO \sim \triangle DAO$.